# Python EIG matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have

```
k=linalg.eig(Ki)
```

where Ki for example is :

```
[[ 1.84026465 -0.463138  ]
 [-0.463138    3.83931947]]
```

and result k is:

```
(array([ 1.73817877,  3.94140535]), array([[-0.97655787,  0.21525501],
       [-0.21525501, -0.97655787]]))
```

**how can I display just biggest value from k (I don't know why are there 2 array, if I calculate by hand only first array is result..) ? I'm looking something like max(k)...anyone know?**

Comment: The two arrays correspond to the eigenvalues (first array) and eigenvectors (second array). Are you after the largest eigenvalue?

Comment: I think it's the other way around, Simon.  There are two eigenvalues and two 1x2 eigenvectors.  Otherwise you're spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[linalg.eig](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html#numpy-linalg-eig) returns two arrays, first the eigenvalues, then the eigenvectors.

If you want the maximimum eigenvalue, then

```
vals,vecs=linalg.eig(Ki)
max_eigenvalue = vals.max()
```

Comment: Thanks for this obligation! Problem SOLVED :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the eigenvalues:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues{{1.84026465%2C-0.463138}%2C%20{-0.21525501%2C%20-0.97655787}}

And the eigenvectors:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors{{1.84026465%2C-0.463138}%2C+{-0.21525501%2C+-0.97655787}}